# Removing row from table by clicking close icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to delete individual row in the table by clicking close icon. How can I achieve that result? By default I wrote code for remove all rows. I wonder also about better way to print rows in table: [link -> jsfiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/sa12bhLv/11/)

```
$.each(result, function (i, field) {
    $("#persons").append(
      '<tr class="person">' + 
      '<td>' + field.id + '</td><td>' + field.last_name + '</td>' + 
      '<td>' + field.first_name + '</td><td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></td>' +
      '</tr>');
});

$("i.fa").click(function() {
      $(".person").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your click event handler to following. Use [jQuery.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$("i.fa").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

For reference, [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sa12bhLv/14/)

Answer (score 2):

You need `this` to get clicked object.

```
$("i.fa").click(function() {
      $(this).parents(".person").remove();
});
```

Here is working example.

```js
var result = [{"id":1,"last_name":"Kowalski","first_name":"Jan"},{"id":2,"last_name":"Nowak","first_name":"Adam"},{"id":3,"last_name":"Kowal","first_name":"Zbigniew"}];

$(document).ready(function () {
      $.each(result, function (i, field) {
        $("#persons").append(
          '<tr class="person">' + 
          '<td>' + field.id + '</td><td>' + field.last_name + '</td>' + 
          '<td>' + field.first_name + '</td><td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-times-circle">X</i></td>' +
          '</tr>');
      });

      $("i.fa").click(function() {
      $(this).parents(".person").remove();
});

      $("#search").keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#persons tr").filter(function () {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row center-block">
   <div class="col-sm-8 mt-3">
    <h1 id="whitelistHeader" class="text-center"></h1>
   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-7">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
     <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">Search:</span>
     </div>
     <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. Kowalski" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>

    <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th style="color:red;text-align:center">DELETE</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="persons"></tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this).closest('tr').remove();` to delete the corresponding row for the delete icon you clicked:

```js
var result = [{"id":1,"last_name":"Kowalski","first_name":"Jan"},{"id":2,"last_name":"Nowak","first_name":"Adam"},{"id":3,"last_name":"Kowal","first_name":"Zbigniew"}];

$(document).ready(function () {
      $.each(result, function (i, field) {
        $("#persons").append(
          '<tr class="person">' + 
          '<td>' + field.id + '</td><td>' + field.last_name + '</td>' + 
          '<td>' + field.first_name + '</td><td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-times-circle">X</i></td>' +
          '</tr>');
      });

      $("i.fa").click(function() {
         $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      });

      $("#search").keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#persons tr").filter(function () {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row center-block">
   <div class="col-sm-8 mt-3">
    <h1 id="whitelistHeader" class="text-center"></h1>
   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-7">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
     <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">Search:</span>
     </div>
     <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. Kowalski" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>

    <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th style="color:red;text-align:center">DELETE</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="persons"></tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```